# Axios POST request not sending query string values as integers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, axios

I'm trying to send a POST request to my .NET API. The values that I need to send are NumeroCupon as an int, NumeroReserva as an int and CapthcaToken as a string. The values for NumeroCupon and NumeroReserva are taken from the url query strings. So, I do the following:
`

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const numCupon = urlParams.get('numerocupon');
const numReserva = urlParams.get('numeroreserva');
const captchaToken = getCookie('captchaToken');

const requestParams = {
    NumeroCupon: parseInt(numCupon),
    NumeroReserva: parseInt(numReserva),
    CaptchaToken: captchaToken
}

axios.post(cuponDataURL, JSON.stringify(requestParams), { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

Where requestParams is the body of the post request.

Now, for the API to read the body values correctly, it needs to recieve the correct data types, this means that my back-end is only reading the captchaToken but the expected int values is just reading them as 0s.

What makes me think that is sending the wrong data types? Because if I create a new string, parse it to int and send it, it does work.

Also, if I change my back-end and I select that I want to recieve strings instead of ints it actually reades the values.

So basically this works if I configure the back-end to work with strings:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const numCupon = urlParams.get('numerocupon');
const numReserva = urlParams.get('numeroreserva');
const captchaToken = getCookie('captchaToken');

const requestParams = {
    NumeroCupon: numCupon,
    NumeroReserva: numReserva,
    CaptchaToken: captchaToken
}
```

And this also works if my back-end is configured to work with ints (as intended):

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const numCupon = urlParams.get('numerocupon');
const numReserva = urlParams.get('numeroreserva');
const captchaToken = getCookie('captchaToken');

const requestParams = {
    NumeroCupon: 117,
    NumeroReserva: 343,
    CaptchaToken: captchaToken
}
```

So my question reduces to, how can I send my query string values as an int with axios?

Comment: There is no way to send numbers using a query string

Comment: @Konrad No, I know. That's why I'm using the ParseInt. But still, it isn't working.

Comment: Now I see that you send body instead of query strings. The two problems seem to be unrelated. Add `console.log(requestParams)` and see if you get the correct values